# Sort dates in a DataFrame according to column keeping other columns' values using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataset like this *(extra here means multiple extra columns)*:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'id_police':['p123','p123','p123','b123','b123'],
                   'dateeffe':['24/01/2018','24/11/2017','25/02/2018','24/02/2018','24/02/2018'],
                   'date_fin':['23/03/2018','23/12/2017','26/03/2018','25/02/2018','25/02/2018'],
                   'prime':[0,20,10,20,30],
                   'prime2':[0,30,10,20,0],
                   'extra':[12,12,13,15,20],
                   ...
})
###
  id_police    dateeffe    date_fin  prime  prime2  extra  ...
0      p123  24/01/2018  23/03/2018      0       0     12  ...
1      p123  24/11/2017  23/12/2017     20      30     12  ...
2      p123  25/02/2018  26/03/2018     10      10     13  ...
3      b123  24/02/2018  25/02/2018     20      20     15  ...
4      b123  24/02/2018  25/02/2018     30       0     20  ...
```

I want to sort dates (e.g 2017 then 2018...) in each column `id_police`, also, I will have to keep max prime in each duplicate `dateeffe` and `date_fin` like in 3 & 4 having same `id_police`.

This is the expected output:

```
  id_police    dateeffe    date_fin  prime  prime2  extra  ...
0      p123  24/11/2017  23/12/2017     20      30     12  ...
1      p123  24/01/2018  23/03/2018      0       0     12  ...
2      p123  25/02/2018  26/03/2018     10      10     13  ...
3      b123  24/02/2018  25/02/2018     30      20     15  ...
```

To find maximum prime & prime2 I used this:

```
df = df.groupby(['id_police','dateeffe','date_fin'],as_index=False).agg({'prime':'max','prime2':'max'})
```

This is what I tried but it groups all and I lose the column extra...

```
df1 = df.sort_values(['dateeffe','date_fin']).groupby('id_police', as_index=False).apply(lambda x: x)
```

I looked everywhere and I appreciate your help, thanks in advance!

Comment: question , prime2 20 is greater than 0 and prime1 30 is greater then 20 , from the rank side , they have the equal weighted , why you pick row 3 rather than row 4

Comment: actually the id is resetted in this case and neither are picked, I picked the maximum on each row for same dates

Comment: Ok Just let me simplify the question why row 4 getting deleted ?

Comment: row 4 is not picked, I pick maximum per column for prime & prime2. but keep other details that are duplicated like dates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came up with a solution based on **two-step groupby**.

To facilitate the sort by dates in `groupby`, let's start with
changing the type of both dates to `datetime`:

```
df.dateeffe = pd.to_datetime(df.dateeffe)
df.date_fin = pd.to_datetime(df.date_fin)
```

The second part is a copy of the solution by *Wen-Ben*, to create a dictionary
of aggregation functions (a smart solution, no need to do it any other way):

```
d = {'prime': 'max', 'prime2': 'max'}
d1 = dict.fromkeys(df.columns.difference(
    ['id_police', 'dateeffe', 'date_fin', 'prime', 'prime2']), 'first')
d.update(d1)
```

Then let's define a function containing the second-step `groupby`, applying
the above aggregation functions:

```
def fn(xx):
    return xx.groupby(['dateeffe', 'date_fin'], as_index=False).agg(d)
```

And the only thing to do is the actual computation, i.e. the first-step `groupby`,
applying the second-step `groupby` defined above:

```
df.groupby('id_police', sort=False).apply(fn)\
    .reset_index(level=1, drop=True).reset_index()
```

Note the difference between both `groupby` cases:

- The first-step `groupby` contains `sort=False`, so the original
  order of `id_police` is maintained.
- But the second-step `groupby` has no `sort` argument, so this
  groupping takes care for sort, on both dates.

And a bit of explanation concerning both calls of `reset_index`:

`df.groupby('id_police', sort=False).apply(fn)` produces a DataFrame with
the following multiindex:

```
id_police  
p123      0
          1
          2
b123      0
```

So the first `reset_index` completely removes level 1 (*0*, *1*, *2*, *0*)
(`drop=True`).

But the second `reset_index` actually changes the only remaining
index level (*p123*, *p123*, *p123*, *b123*) into a regular column and
creates the default index (consecutive numbers from 0).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I like your answer better because that's what I wanted, two groupby instead of one. Thanks again!

Answer (score 4):

Check the ouput with `first`

```
df = df.groupby(['id_police','dateeffe','date_fin'],as_index=False).agg({'prime':'max','prime2':'max','extra':'first'})
df
Out[482]: 
  id_police    dateeffe    date_fin  prime  prime2  extra
0      b123  24/02/2018  25/02/2018     30      20     15
1      p123  24/01/2018  23/03/2018      0       0     12
2      p123  24/11/2017  23/12/2017     20      30     12
3      p123  25/02/2018  26/03/2018     10      10     13
```

---

Update

```
d={'prime':'max','prime2':'max'}
d1=dict.fromkeys(df.columns.difference(['id_police','dateeffe','date_fin','prime','prime2']),'first')
d.update(d1)
df=df.groupby(['id_police','dateeffe','date_fin'],as_index=False).agg(d)
Out[501]: 
  id_police    dateeffe    date_fin  prime  prime2  extra
0      b123  24/02/2018  25/02/2018     30      20     15
1      p123  24/01/2018  23/03/2018      0       0     12
2      p123  24/11/2017  23/12/2017     20      30     12
3      p123  25/02/2018  26/03/2018     10      10     13
df.dateeffe=pd.to_datetime(df.dateeffe)
df.date_fin=pd.to_datetime(df.date_fin)
df=df.sort_values(['id_police','dateeffe','date_fin'])
```

Comment: what if I have 30 columns instead of one column extra? this is why I used extra.... thanks for your answer and time...

Comment: But wait, the dates are not sorted... Please update :-(

Comment: The problem is, I need to sort within each `id_police` because some id_police in the database have similar intervals... So, I should sort withing the groupby sentence... I'm sure this is possible.. thank u!

Comment: @SabiriS. df=df.sort_values(['id_police','dateeffe','date_fin'])

Comment: Do not using apply with two group, since it will slow down the whole process . If you have big dataframe , apply with lambda x : x.groupby will taking way to long @SabiriS.happy coding